# Resolving urls to get the correct URL address to access through a browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string that I get from my session object which contains the page of the previous page.

```
  dim myStr as string = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/mywebsite/modules/weather/tester.aspx"
```

What I am trying to achieve is to call the page upon a click event by resolving the url to the local address. Something like

```
  http://localhost:1234/modules/weather/tester.aspx
```

I was wondering what I can do to achieve this. I have tried

```
    Dim myTestUrl As String = Page.ResolveUrl(myStr)
```

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: you can't really do that as thats up to the iisconfig. if you have a relative url to that other page, then you can do it.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I'm curious why you have file paths in the first place? If you're just tracking browsing history, would it make sense to keep an array of last visited pages by URL in the user's session, or even in a cookie? Or can the functionality be done client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the url for the previous page you could just use 
`Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()`

Comment: That hasn't worked. I just gives me the currrent page as thats where the click event resides. What I am after is just getting the ip/domain etc... In this case it was locahost:4086 So basically I just want to get the address part. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @user3036965 Try using Request.UrlReferrer.Authority; then

Comment: @user3036965 I still didn't really understand what part you wanted haha, but if it was the other way around and you just want the /Page/xxx part you can use Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;

Comment: Please tell me which of the options I gave you was the correct one that you were after and I will update the answer accordingly since you chose to accept it

Comment: I did this to get what I wanted with your help. Session("pageUrl") = "http://" & Request.UrlReferrer.Authority + Request.FilePath

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to maintain a global or config variable storing each of the base paths.

```
var siteRoot = "localhost:1234";
var fileRoot = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/mywebsite";
```

Then you could have a function that converts between the two. For example `FileToWebPath(string path)` and `WebToFilePath(string path)`. You could even get by with just one function but this should outline the idea.

Some simple replace and concatenation and you should be good to go.